# What is the relationship between buckets and partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a relationship between the Partitions of an RDD and the Buckets which the contents of the RDD get mapped to before a shuffle operation ?

Secondly, will all key value pairs with same key be shuffled to the same bucket or is the distribution of key value pairs to buckets random? Does specifying a partitioner (hash/range) have any effect on this distribution?

Comment: If take you take a look at the `HashShuffleWriter` implementation you'll see there is pretty much no distinction. `bucketId` is determined using `partitioner.getPartition` on the `key`.

Comment: @zero323 So, by that logic, the `records: Iterator[Product2[K, V]]` that is passed to the `write()` method of the `HashShuffleWriter` contains the actual content of the buckets ?

Comment: That's my understanding. Take a look at the docstring of the [ShuffleWriterGroup](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/shuffle/FileShuffleBlockResolver.scala#L54).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a relationship between the Partitions of an RDD and the Buckets which the contents of the RDD get mapped to before a shuffle operation ?

If you ask about **bucketed tables** (after `bucketBy` and `spark.table("bucketed_table")`) I think the answer is yes.

Let me show you what I mean by answering yes.

```
val large = spark.range(1000000)
scala> println(large.queryExecution.toRdd.getNumPartitions)
8

scala> large.write.bucketBy(4, "id").saveAsTable("bucketed_4_id")
18/04/18 22:00:58 WARN HiveExternalCatalog: Persisting bucketed data source table `default`.`bucketed_4_id` into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format, which is NOT compatible with Hive.

scala> println(spark.table("bucketed_4_id").queryExecution.toRdd.getNumPartitions)
4
```

In other words, the number of partitions (after a bucketed table is loaded) is exactly the number of buckets (you defined while saving it).

> Secondly, will all key value pairs with same key be shuffled to the same bucket or is the distribution of key value pairs to buckets random?

Spark 2.3 (and I believe the earlier versions work alike) does bucketing per partition (a writer task), i.e. every partition has the number of buckets you defined.

In the above case, you will end up with 8 (partitions) x 4 (buckets) = 32 bucket files (that with two extra lines for `_SUCCESS` and the header gives 34).

```
$ ls -ltr spark-warehouse/bucketed_4_id | wc -l
      34
```

> Does specifying a partitioner (hash/range) have any effect on this distribution?

I think so since a partitioner is used to distribute data across partitions.